# Mysql issue with WHERE in clause

Tags: mysql, sql

What is wrong with my "where in" clause in mysql?

My two tables `SEATS` and `REGISTERS` look like this

```
--    SEATS                          REGISTERS
| seat_id (int) |     | register_id (int)| seat_id (varchar) |
|===============|     |==================|===================|
|     102       |     |      3           |   102,103,104     |
|     103       |     |    234           |   546,547         |
```

The query to fetch the matching results is

```
SELECT * FROM Seats s, Registers r 
WHERE s.seat_id IN (r.seat_ids) 
GROUP BY s.seat_id
```

Can someone figure out what's wrong ? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IN` requires the list to be a literal list, not a comma-delimited string. Use `FIND_IN_SET` for that:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(s.seat_id, r.seat_ids)
```

Comment: wow, this really works :O never heard of find_in_set before! Going to save it forever! hehe :) many thanks

Comment: It's right there on the documentation page of string functions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the seat_ids to int, else maintain a separate table where the linkage of seats and registers are maintained.

Join like below can help club results of 2 tables

```
SELECT * FROM Seats s
JOIN Registers r ON s.seat_id = r.seat_ids
```

But this will require same data type of Seats seat_id & Registers seat_ids

Else what @Barmar said can be used